# multiplication game python

Tags: python, random, multiplication

I am supposed to write a program in python that asks the user how many multiplication questions they want, and it randomly gives them questions with values from 1 to 10. Then it spits out the percentage they got correct. My code keeps repeating the same set of numbers and it also doesn't stop at the number the user asked for. Could you tell me what's wrong?

```
import random
import math

gamenumber = int(input("How many probems do you want?\n"))
num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
num_2 = random.randint(1,10)

def main():

    random.seed()
    count = 0
    while count < gamenumber:
        guess = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "."))

        answer = str(num_1*num_2)
        correct = guess == answer

        if guess == answer:
            print("Correct!")
        else wrong:
            print("Sorry, the answer is", answer, ".")

        result = correct/wrong   

    print("You got ", "%.1f"%result, "of the problems.")

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems you mentioned

> My code keeps repeating the same set of numbers

This is no surprise, as you set your `num_1` and `num_2` (1) outside the `main` function and (2) outside the main `while` loop. A simple correction is:

```
    while count < gamenumber:
        num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
```

> My code doens't stop at the number asked for:

There again, no surprise, as you never increment the `count` counter: you always have `count < gamenumber`. 
A simple correction is:

```
    while count < gamenumber:
        num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
        guess = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "."))
        answer = str(num_1*num_2)

        count += 1
```

Here, the `count += 1` means `add 1 to count *in place*`. You could also do `count = count + 1` but it's a bit less efficient as you create a temporary variable (`count + 1`) that you don't really need.

### Other problems

- You never define `wrong`
- You define `gamenumber` outside the function. While it's not an issue in this case, it'd be easier to use `gamenumber` as an argument of `main`, as it's the variable that drives the game.
- Your `result` is defined in the loop. You probably want to increment a counter for each good answer and print the result after the main loop.
- Your `result` is calculated as `correct/wrong`. While I'm sure you meant `correct/gamenumber`, you have to be extra careful: `count` and `gamenumber` are integers, and dividing integers is no the same as dividing floats. For example, `2/3` gives `0`, but `2/float(3)` gives `0.6666666`. So, we'll have to use a float somewhere.
- You want to print a percentage: your `result` should then be `result=correct*100./gamenumber`.
- You don't want to `gamenumber` to be 0, otherwise your `result` will be undefined.

So, all in all, your `main` function should be

```
def main(gamenumber):
    random.seed()
    count = 0
    correct = 0
    while count < gamenumber:
        num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
        num_2 = random.randint(1,10)
        guess = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "."))
        answer = str(num_1*num_2)
        count += 1

        if guess == answer:
            correct += 1
            print("Correct!")
        else wrong:
            print("Sorry, the answer is", answer, ".")

    if gamenumber > 1:
        result = correct * 100./gamenumber  

    print("You got ", "%.1f"%result, "of the problems.")
```

Answer (score 4):

You only assign to `num_1` and `num_2` once.  Their values never change; how can your numbers change?  Furthermore, you don't increment `count`, so its original value is always compared against `gamenumber`.

You need to assign a new random number to your two variables and increment your counter.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to increment `count` in your loop and `num_1` and `num_2` don't get new values.

Comment: how do i reassign those numbers? I can't believe i forgot the count! so that explains that. but im new to python and im not sure how to reassign the numbers to be random every time it asks a multiplication question

Comment: The same way you'd do it the first time.

Answer (score 1):

The most glaring issue to me is that you have an infinite loop; you don't increase `count` anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're only generating the question numbers once, before you start looping. You need to generate num_1 and num_2 every time, before the user is asked a question.
2. You never actually update the count value after initializing it, so your loop will go on forever.

Comment: thank you. how would i count the number of times the user got the question right in order to figure out the percentage of questions they answered correctly?

Comment: I guess some of these answers might be a bit unclear for you. I think that's because people want you to try figuring it out for yourself as much as possible. 

I would suggest writing out the logic in words. That should help your understanding. Try pretending that instead of the program, you are running the game for a person. You would probably ask them the question, and keep asking them until they've had enough (count is reached). Every time they give an answer, you count it if it's correct. You remember the count of correct answers - by having a separate count variable for correct answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
import math
```

spelling of "problems" is wrong

```
gamenumber = int(input("How many probems do you want?\n"))
```

move these next two lines inside the loop

```
num_1 = random.randint(1,10)
num_2 = random.randint(1,10)

def main():

    random.seed()
    count = 0
    while count < gamenumber:
```

You can use `"What is {}x{}?".format(num1, num2)` here.

```
        guess = int(input("What is " + str(num_1) + "x" + str(num_2) + "."))

        answer = str(num_1*num_2)
```

Is this supposed to count the correct answers? should be `correct += guess == answer`

```
       correct = guess == answer
```

Do you mean to count the number of wrong answers? `wrong += guess != answer`

```
        if guess == answer:
            print("Correct!")
```

`else wrong:` is a syntax error  `else: #wrong` perhaps?

```
        else wrong:
            print("Sorry, the answer is", answer, ".")
```

This isn't how to compute a percentage. You should use `correct*100/gamenumber` and dedent to match the `print()`

```
        result = correct/wrong   

    print("You got ", "%.1f"%result, "of the problems.")

main()
```

Also you're not incrementing `count` anywhere. It's easier to just use

```
for count in range(gamenumber):
```

instead of the `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

Python is a procedural language. It executes statements in your method body from top to bottom. This line:

`num_1 = random.randint(1,10)`

is an assignment statement.  It does *not* equate `num_1` with a random process for assessing its value; it evaluates an expression - by calling `random.randint(1,10)` - and assigns that value to `num_1`, once.

You must force another call to random.randint to obtain another random number, and you must have a statement assign a value to num_1 each time you want num_1's value to change.

Comment: okay awesome I figured that out and the numbers are now random each time :). However would you be able to help me figure out how to find the percentage the user gets the questions right? so it would be how many times they got it write divided by total number of questions.

Answer (score 0):

Write a multiplication game program for kids. The program should give the player ten randomly generated multiplication questions to do. After each, the program should tell them whether they got it right or wrong and what the correct answer is

```
from random import randint 

for i in range (1,11):
    num1 = randint (1,10)
    num2 = randint (1,10)
    print ("Question",i,":",num1,"*",num2,"=", end = " ")
    guess = int (input())
    answer = num1*num2
    if guess == answer:
        print ("Right!")
    else:
        print ("Wrong. The answer is: ",answer)
```